# Does colon have some new syntax in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Please check out this line of code:
https://github.com/gaearon/dnd-core/blob/master/src/actions/dragDrop.js#L16

```
export function beginDrag(sourceIds, {
    publishSource = true,
    clientOffset = null,
    getSourceClientOffset
}: options = {}) { console.log('foo'); }
```

What kind of ES6 syntax is the colon here?

Comment: It's an ES6 syntax error.

Comment: Looks like poorly-done flowtype?